# Spring MVC Java Config issues

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying to do an example to change the xml config to Java config for Spring MVC. But my simple example is not working. On running this project on server, I can't see any beans initializing or the dispatcher servlet name on console.
and I get 404 error on running the  http://localhost:8080/Servlet3Example/

I have created a maven project and following is my code:

```
package com.project.config;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MyDispatcherServlet extends      AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    System.out.println("get root config");
    //return new Class[]{RootConfig.class};
    return null;
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    System.out.println("get web config");
    return new Class[]{WebConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    System.out.println("in dispatcher servlet");
    return new String[] {"/"};
}
```

}

And the WebConfig is:

```
package com.project.config;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.project.controllers"})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new      InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    return viewResolver;
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
```

}

And controller:

```
package com.project.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String home()
{
    return "home";
}
}
```

Comment: This all seems to look fine to me. Are you getting any errors in your server logs? Also try putting some breakpoints in MyDispatcherServlet and MyConfig to see if these are getting initialised.

Comment: try `http://localhost:8080/`

Comment: No, MyDispatcherServlet seems not getting initialising. Config too, no bean's reference in console. No errrors in console.

Comment: Have you tried `@Override
 protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
  return new Class<?>[] {
   WebConfig.class
  };
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Can you please change `@ComponentScan` to `@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.project.*"})`